# redux-form - Submit only edited field

Tags: javascript, forms, reactjs, redux-form

In this example, I have a form to update user information and it is written in React with redux-form 6.5. I'm a newbie with this stack.

The render form function is like:

```js
render() {
    const { handleSubmit } = this.props;        
    return (
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.handleFormSubmit.bind(this))}>
        <Field name="name" component="input" type="text"/>
        <Field name="surname" component="input" type="text"/>
        <button action="submit">Sign in</button>
      </form>
    );
```

I have the reduxForm connection:

```js
const extendedComponent = reduxForm({
  form: 'userdetail',
  validate
})(UserDetail);
```

And I have submit handler:

```js
 handleFormSubmit(user) {
    // TODO: how can I get only the touched fields?
    this.props.updateUser(user);
  }
```

I receive correctly the object user after the validation, I send the PUT call and everything works fine.

But I don't like to send all the data in the PUT, **my wish is to send only the edited data to the PUT**.
I understand that I could retrieve the initialValues and compare all fields.

There is another way? How can I get only the touched fields?

Which is the best practice to do this?

It seems to me a common task and I'm not finding anything about that, so I am assuming I'm completely missing the point.

Thank you all :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the maintainer of the `redux-form` project: ["That's not a feature of the library"](https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/issues/701).

In that response, he recommends handling the diffing yourself or using a pre-existing library, like [object-diff](https://github.com/srcagency/object-diff).

For example like this:

```
import diff from 'object-diff'

handleFormSubmit(user, dispatch, props) {
  const { initialValues } = props 
  const changedValues = diff(initialValues, user)
  this.props.updateUser(changedValues);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I miss that question.